# Zend Framework coding standards

Tags: model-view-controller, zend-framework, model

In case you're not sick of hearing about my chat application...
The main part of the application, the piece that does all of the back end work is in the "models" directory. The class is called AEDC_Model_Chat (AEDC is the namespace) but this particular class isn't actually an "object". It is never instantiated, and it only exposes static methods.

So, I am thinking this isn't actually a model, and doesn't really belong in "models".
Any thoughts?

Comment: FYI: if you want use [Zend Framework Naming Conventions](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.naming-conventions.html) you should rename your class to `Adec_Model_Chat`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, I think it's fine for static based classes to reside in the /models dir. In working with Propel and Doctrine, they have Peer and Table classes (respectively), that are never meant to be instantiated, instead they are meant to implement business logic upon objects to which they are associated. Example dir listings:

```
// Propel
/lib/model/mydb
    Vehicle.php // Instantiable
    VehiclePeer.php // Works with vehicle object(s)

// Doctrine
/lib/model/mydb
    Vehicle.php // Instantiable
    VehicleTable.php // Works with vehicle object(s)
```

**--Update--**

Need to make a correction (doesn't change the answer), with respect to doctrine, the "*Table" classes CAN be instantiated, but they still behave the same as I described above, in that the included methods are meant to work with associated object(s). Your usage of the "static" classes is closer to the way Propel works, and as I mentioned earlier, acceptable to reside in the /model dir.

Comment: That makes sense... I am relatively new to MVC and I do know that I don't want tons of logic in the controllers, so initially it seemed most logical put those things in models. Thanks for your insight.